# Titles are not displaying in Wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress

[Image1: Publishing post with titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHXMc.png)

[Image2: Posts titles are not appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBhSl.png)

Post titles are not with article in page, I am not talking about browser titles (the title appear in  tag) I am concern about the posts that visitors read, these posts are looking awkward without their original titles.

These titles are appearing in latest blog posts widgets and also available in short_codes or excerpts.

I am new in wordpress googled about it but yet no solution.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide complete information. [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) plus add screenshot to support your question for getting help faster.

Comment: how to add screenshot?

Comment: see this screenshot for help https://ibb.co/dGKfj7

Comment: you talking about the detail page title which is not showing under the date MARCH 19, 2018? http://worldcallservices.pk/?p=3847

Comment: Yes detailed page titles under the date March 19, 2018?

Comment: you need to edit the template file `single.php` and search for thsis section `<section class="dnd_section_dd " style="">` if you done with this then add `<h3><?php the_title();?></p>` right after section element

Comment: Thank you noman, above solution works for me, I put your code above <?php the_content();?>

Answer (score 0):

First try this solution

1. Find the post that is missing the Title and Edit it .
2. Scroll down the page and look for the “Format” settings box
3. All my posts with missing titles were set to “Aside”. Changing
   that to “Standard” and all sorted

If it's not work, Than share your website link because sometimes there is a `display:none` css statement applied to your titles SO i can see what is the actual problem after see the live website :)

Comment: Ok , i found some solution . you are using salamat theme old version in which wp_title is not displaying by default .  but this issue is resolved in newest version, you can redownload it. 
see the this [Link] (https://themeforest.net/item/salamat-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/9154551/comments?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=title&from_buyers_and_authors_only=0)

Comment: Where to find this code: <title><?php wp_title(’|’, true, ‘right’); bloginfo( ‘name’ ); ?></title> as I am a beginner, I have no idea about it.

Comment: Login into your website admin-panel than go to Appearance>Editor>header.php